# WPF ListView Always focused last added item?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have many ListViews with the same DataSource with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`
and I'm dynamicaly adding items to this DataSource.

The problem ist when the scrolls appears, **the added items are not visible** unless I move the scrollbar. Should I use another Control for this purpose.. or how can bring the last added item into view (and scrollbars).

Until now I was doing everything directly in XAML, so I'd appreciate such a solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come with a solution:

It cannot be applied in all cases, but it this one it's sufficient!

The trick is to
disable the ListView ScrollBars and surround it with the ScrollViewer.

...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />  <!-- This is needed! -->
       ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

..

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" >
            <ListView Name="MyListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

...

```
</Grid>
```

Then simply if needed call

```
MyScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( !(myListView.Items.IsEmpty) )
{
    myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[myListView.Items.Count - 1]);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to use the method:

```
ListView.ScrollIntoView(ListView.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds suspicious, but even if it's true, you can always call ListView.BringIntoView() method, to... bring selected item into view :).

Comment: Yeah.. you're right, but you have to write a bit more code to select the last item and bring it into view.. but it's a possibility too